# HTML input has both {{}} and ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form which contains two input fields, I want to sync the next input field when user is typing in the first input field by default, and user can edit the second field as they like, below code works fine:

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <input type='text' value='{{name}}'>
    <button ng-click='submit()'>submit</button>
```

However, to be able to get the value of second field, I need to put `ng-model` to  the second field, and once I put `ng-model`, it won't sync anymore.

[This is the example](https://jsfiddle.net/e6huv83n/)

How should I get the second field's value if I don't put a `ng-model` to it.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. I don't think it makes sense to do what you are suggesting. If both input's have the same value, then why would their models be different?

Comment: So basically if the second field is pristine, it should display the value of the first field?

Comment: Hi ralfe, the scenario is like this, this first field is the email field for user, and the second one is the login name, by default we suggest users use their email account as the login name.

Comment: yes @Kos, you are right.

Comment: @Z.Neeson then you probably should make them two separate models, and set the model for login name to email in controller or in ng-init for the first time

Comment: @JKABC you mean it's not possible to make it happen just like normal data binding in angularjs?

Answer (score 3):

You can use ng-change. When user changes input 1 the ng-change method will be called and input2 will be updated .but when user change input 2 nothing will be called .

```
<DIV ng-app='app'>
    <form ng-controller='myController'>
     <input type='text' ng-model='name' ng-change="callMe()"/>
     <input type='text' ng-model="name2"  />{{name2}}
    </form>
</DIV>
```

and controller js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope){

    $scope.callMe =function(){

    $scope.name2=$scope.name;
    }

   //$scope.name
   //$scope.name2
})
```

[update fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvc6neg1/%22Check%20here%22)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `$scope.$watch` Method for your needings.

I have updatet your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6huv83n/3/).

What i did is easy, everytime the model changes, the `$watch` will be called with the new value of the model, then you just need to copy the value into the second model.

Comment: Seems this approach is the best one now.

Answer (score 0):

First approach that came to my mind was to `ng-bind` a property with a setter that would do what you want:

```
 <input type='text' ng-model='nameModel' />
```

then

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    Object.defineProperty($scope, 'nameModel', {
        get: function() { return $scope.name1; },
        set: function(x) { $scope.name1 = $scope.name2 = x; }
    });
});
```

This causes any edit to nameModel to affect both `name1` and `name2`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6huv83n/7/)

You could do a similar wrapper around `name2` to track whether it has ever been modified (dirty/pristine), and have `nameModel` only change `scope.name2` if it is pristine.

[Fiddle with better user experience](https://jsfiddle.net/e6huv83n/8/)

(If you're using [Angular forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms), it tracks the field status for you, so you could directly look at `form.name2.$pristine`.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you need is to set the value to the scope variable.

So your code would then look like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
<input type='text' value="{{name}}" ng-model="somethingelse">
<button ng-click='submit()'>submit</button>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just tried your code on https://jsfiddle.net/e6huv83n/, and can't observe instant update on second input.

Comment: Ah, ok. I see the problem. ng-bind does not work on input tags. I've updated my answer.

Comment: No ralfe, this approach doesn't cover the problem.